# request with JSON returns empty body Nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, requestjs

I'm using `request` to get a list of movies from [yts.ag/api](https://yts.ag/api), and display them in grid of thumbnails, when I click on each of the thumbnail I'm taken to another page which display more details of the movie, when I click the thumbnail first time the data is retrieved, the next time when I click the same movie or other movies the `body` is empty, I'll have to restart the server for it work and it only works with one request after the `request` returns an empty `body`. What seems to be the problem or am I implementing `request` wrong?

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');
var url = 'https://yts.ag/api/v2/movie_details.json';

router.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    url += '?movie_id=' + req.params.id;
    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            if (body) {
                var importJSON = JSON.parse(body);
                res.render('movie', {title: 'Hypertube - Torrent streaming', moviedetails: importJSON.data.movie});
            }else {
                res.render('movie', {title: 'Hypertube - Torrent streaming', moviedetails: false});
            }
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You are putting more stuff in the url every time. You need to do `request(url + '?movie_id=' + req.params.id)`, so that the base url stays unchanged. This will fix the code only working once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the query string containing `movie_id` to the request URL over and over again. So only the first request will work while all subsequent requests have an invalid request URL. Instead create a new request URL in your request callback. In addition, you just ignore any errors that you might get.